# How can I pass a start an HTML5 video at a specific time code using the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, url, video

I need a video to start at a specific time and I need that time to be determined by the value written into the page's URL.

I have this video element:

```
<video id="vid1" width="auto" height="auto" controls autoplay>
  <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

This function successfully cues the video to 50 seconds:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('vid1').addEventListener('loadedmetadata',   function() {
  this.currentTime = 50;
}, false);
</script>
```

Let's say my URL is http://www.mywebaddress.com/video1.html?50

I want to grab the value "50" from the URL and pass it into my function so that I can dynamically change the time to which the video cues.

I've got this function to grab the value from the URL:

```
<script>
function GetUrlValue(VarSearch){
    var TimeCode = window.location.search.substring(1);
}
</script>
```

How do I rewrite the cue function now so that it sets the value to whatever value chosen in the URL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this :

```
<script>
var TimeCode;
function GetUrlValue(){
    TimeCode = parseInt(window.location.href.split("?")[1]);
}
</script>
```

And then :

```
GetUrlValue();
document.getElementById('vid1').addEventListener('loadedmetadata',   function() {
  this.currentTime = TimeCode;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the call of `this.currentTime` to

```
document.getElementById('vid1').addEventListener('loadedmetadata',   function() {
  this.currentTime = window.location.search.substring(1);
}, false);
```

or in sticking to your variable mechanism you could do

```
var TimeCode = window.location.search.substring(1);
document.getElementById('vid1').addEventListener('loadedmetadata',   function() {
  this.currentTime = TimeCode;
}, false);
```